# log4j // log24j // unrecognized format specifier

Tags: java, maven, log4j, log4j2

I have upgraded from slf4j 2.8.2 to sl4j 2.17.2 and now see this error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger DOM element is - not a <log4j:configuration> element.
```

Things I have tried:

1. adding maven shade plugin to exclude .dat file
2. un packaging jar files between versions to check if the log4j2 config file is different and has been over written somehow (it has not).
3. Checking mvn dependencies for any differences between the two installations (there is none apart from expected logging version).

does anyone know what this could be?